# How to draw dynamic line in RDLC Report

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I'm try to generate dynamic line for column in RDLC report. Start and end point of line are not fixed, it depends upon data coming from database. I tried different code but no luck.

Please refer image for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The lines in SSRS can't be set dynamically. The closest you could get to this would be to use a Line Chart or Sparkline. These both typically go left to right, not down. So it would be very difficult to simulate what you show in the screenshot.

You could try making separate charts stacked vertically that look like they're connected, but I don't think you would be able to get those nice dots at the vertices if you can even get rid of all the padding. And objects can't overlap. So you can't even add images over spots that you want to. You also can't rotate charts.

Sorry for the vague answer, but I would hazard to say it's not possible to do exactly what you're showing there. Hopefully this at least helps explain why.

Comment: @DineshPatil I know this probably wasn't the answer you wanted to hear. Given that there were no other answers, please mark it accordingly.